# Why remove tfilin before talis?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, tallit-gadol, priorities

I've heard why we put on the talis before tfilin (tadir or maylin bakodesh), but why take it off in the reverse order?

Comment: lacer6, thanks for your interesting question and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1816/lacer6), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: of interest: The Lubavitcher Rebbe discusses the "Shiur Hefsek" of Sukkah, Tefillin, Tallit, and smell. There the Rebbe points out that the time of Tallit is longer than Tefillin, since it is put on before. - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15787&pgnum=35

Comment: @Menachem, how is that related?

Comment: @YDK: The idea that one wears his Tallit longer than he wears his Tefillin (which is why the shiur hefsek is longer by a tallit than by tefillin) could be used to say that not only is the Tallit put on first, but taken off last.

Comment: @Menachem, isn't that backwards?  He says the hefsek is based on the length of time worn.  We are looking for a basis of that length.

Comment: @YDK: True. Which is why I said "of interest". The shiur for tefillin == 2 or 3 hours. The shiur for tallit == many hours.

Comment: sorta similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31163/759

Answer (score 5):

[Rivivos Efraim 6:24](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1084&pgnum=82) mentions a question he was asked with the questioner giving a few reasons why Tefilin is removed first.

A: It is done practically in order that the Talis should be available first when you put it on the following day. By putting away the Tefilin first the Talis is at the top of the bag.

B: Since on Rosh Chodesh and Chol HaMoed we remove Tefilin prior to the end of Davening and we remain in a Talis for the rest of the Tefila, therefore at all times we remove the Tefilin first.

C: Since a person is only allowed to wear his Tefilin when he has a Guf Naki, therefore we do not leave it on longer than necessary and it is removed first.

Comment: Gershon, it seems from the read that those 3 ideas are from the shoel who opines that one who puts on a talis just for kavod hatzibur may remove his talis first. R' Ephraim's answer is that based on the sources, there is no differentiation "al pi kabala".  Though R' Ephraim calls the above 3 ideas "miskablim al halev".