# What should be done if the shel rosh first is taken out first?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, mistakes

Let's assume that [one puts on the shel yad (hand-tefillin) before the shel rosh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31164/5323), and based on that, should be careful to take out the shel yad first (because of "אין מעבירין על המצוות").

**What should one do if one accidentally removed the shel rosh (head-tefillin) from the tefillin bag first?** Should he put it on (אין מעבירין על מצוות), or put it down and put on the shel yad?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31163/5323

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 25:6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x377), **one should put on the shel yad first.**

The reason for this is given in the Mishna Berura, ad loc ([23](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=65)) -- since the reason for the order of "shel yad first" is given explicitly in <s>[Double AA's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31164/5323)</s> the gemara ([Menachos 36a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=36&format=pdf)), we keep by that order, even though אין מעבירין על המצוות is contradicted.

Comment: Shulchan Aruch linking [supported by MY referencer 4.0.0](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18601537#18601537). Check it out!